# How to send html form data to excel file

Tags: javascript, html

how to send form data like username and email field data by using java script then it has to be stored in excel file by clicking a button and also that code should run on all browsers??
Before I was running this vb code under script tag executed in IE even there also I can't see any data filled in that  excel file.

```
Sub sample()  
          Dim iRow  
          Set objExcel = CreateObject ("Excel.Application")  
          Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Users\users.xlsx")  
          objExcel.Application.Visible = True  
          ObjWorkbook.Windows (1).Visible = True  
          Set XlSheet =objWorkbook.Sheets (1)  
          XlSheet.Activate  
          iRow = 1  
          With objExcel  
              Do while .Cells (iRow, 1).value <> ""  
                  .Cells (iRow, 1).activate  
                  iRow = iRow + 1  
              Loop  
                 .Cells (iRow, 1).value=Document.GetElementsByName("fname")(0).Value  
                 .Cells (iRow, 2).value=Document.GetElementsByName("lname")(0).Value  
                 .Cells (iRow, 3).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add1")(0).Value  
                 .Cells (iRow, 4).value=Document.GetElementsByName("Add2")(0).Value  
                 MsgBox "Data Added Successfully”, vbinformation  
                 Document.GetElementsByName ("fname") (0).Value=""  
                 Document.GetElementsByName ("lname") (0).Value=""  
                 Document.GetElementsByName ("Add1") (0).Value=""  
                 Document.GetElementsByName ("Add2") (0).Value=""  
             End With  
             ObjWorkbook.Save  
             ObjWorkbook.Close  
             Set objWorkbook = Nothing  
             Set objExcel = Nothing  
         End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that what you're trying to do is not possible, first and foremost because you **cannot** edit any existing file on your computer through the browser. Not in place, anyways.

The two most simple solutions I can think of are either:

1. Request the file from javascript ("upload" it). Edit it manually from there (you will not be able to use Excel's API from there, but maybe [this library here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) will help you achieving what you're trying. Then have the user re-download the file.
2. Start a simple server that changes the file **for** you (maybe even from VBA itself? I really have no good knowledge of its capabilities). Then you can create a simple html form that interacts with that server.

Last thing, hopefully I'm not outta line here but it seems as if you're a little bit unsure about how web technologies work. If you're interested, I suggest that you go on to read a little about html5, javascript and how basic client-server communication works over http.

Good luck!